# Java Script /Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I've looked at a few scripts from google but there are little bit too complicated I just want a simple solution. i got an array with some data (20 string) and a textfield and i need to show a autosuggestion using only javascript/css "***NOT in JQUERY***"

Comment: `autocomplete` isn't like doing `1 + 5`, so if it's a bit complicated, just bear with it and try to adopt :)

Comment: @ASIK_RAJA_A its a bot complicated. Not really easy but just try to understand the code which I have included in the answer below. Would be helpful.

Comment: You program "in a language" but "with a library". Contrary to popular opinion jQuery is a *library*, not a language!

Comment: what scripts have you checked out already?